# transferring bitmap between activities

Tags: android, bitmap

bmp1 is a bitmap image

in activity 1 I have the following code

```
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                bmp1.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
                byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
regIntent.putExtra("chosenImage",byteArray);
```

then in activity2 i do this.

```
Intent regIntent = getIntent();
 byte[] byteArray = regIntent.getByteArrayExtra("chosenImage");
        bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray, 0, byteArray.length);
        bmp = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmp, 150, 200, true);
```

i then display the image using this code:

```
 ImageView mainBookImage = findViewById(R.id.mainBookImage); //uncoment to load image
        mainBookImage.setImageBitmap(bmp);
```

however i just end up getting a blank image, any ideas why?

Comment: Don't attach the Bitmap directly into your Intent but send only the Uri of your image.

Comment: uri? the image isnt stored on the device its from a web download on the fly

Comment: After you download then store it in your device. Actually Intent can only carry a small amount of data, assuming your `byte[]` is too huge then expect to see an error.

Answer (score 1):

In your First Activity.

```
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bmp1.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();

Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setClass(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("chosenImage", byteArray);
startActivity(n);
```

In your Second Activity oncreate()

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
byte[] byteArray = extras.getByteArray("chosenImage");
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray, 0, byteArray.length);

//  And Set Image in Imageview like this

ImageView mainBookImage = findViewById(R.id.mainBookImage);
if (bmp != null) {
        mainBookImage.setImageBitmap(bmp);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to implement different approach.

If its mandatory for you to pass the bitmap itself, then you can pass the `Bitmap` object as it is since it implements Parcelable. It would be as simple as `regIntent.putExtra("chosenImage",bmp1);` and in activity 2:

`final Bitmap bmp1= regIntent.getParcelableExtra("chosenImage");`

However, this approach is highly discouraged since it will cost a lot of memory and impact responsiveness of your application. Moreover on low end devices this could lead to crash due to lack of memory and also limitation on data size which could be transferred through Intents.

One approach could be to store it in a file and then pass the path of file through Intent extra. In `Activity2` you can retrieve the path -> load the image in `Bitmap` -> use in `ImageView`.